# Mod_Rewrite to clean URLs

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to create a WordPress style URL system where I can have the user create a page, which automatically creates a "slug" version of it.

I will be using index.php to query the database to match the slug to the page.

I have tried copying parts of WordPress' .htaccess, however shows a 404 error.

My URL format is similar to the following:

```
www.mysite.com/about
www.mysite.com/rentals/page1
```

My .htaccess file looks like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Once I get the htaccess part solved, how do I the slug from the URL? I imagine that even though the URL would be clean it still might possible to send it through as `index.php?page=[SLUG]`

Any ideas on where to start and how to accomplish what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using the following...

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I use `$_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL']`to get the path/page-name.

example... index.php/about

```
$request = strip_tags(trim($_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL']));
$request = rtrim($request, "/"); // remove trailing slash 
$pg = explode('/', $request);
$page = $pg['1'];
// SELECT FROM table WHERE page = $page;
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I tried your .htaccess but I'm getting a 404 error. I get `The requested URL /index.php/about was not found on this server.`  Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks. I did have something similar, however the problem occurs when the link is pressed. If I load just index.php, it works fine. The moment I try to do /PAGE/ it 404s.

Comment: This works flawlessly for me. What else is in the htaccess file?

Comment: Nothing at all. What I have found is that if I do `www.mysite.com/index.php/about` it works, however I don't want to show the `index.php` part.

Comment: try adding a slash to index.php in the htaccess. 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

I use the above example in sub directories with zero issue. for example mysite.com/blog will show the index content, mysite.com/blog/article-page-x-x will show the article.

Comment: Starting to wonder if it's a server configuration issue. I tried another example that supposedly works, and it functions the exact same way yours does. Not that I doubted your answer, just wanted to see if it performed similarly. Any special config settings I need for this to work?

Comment: Wait, does this only work properly if we're at root-level? If I have it stored at www.mysite.com/sandbox/clients/name/site, with /site/ being the "root" of the site, will this cause an issue with that htaccess?

Comment: Got it. The answer to the "Does it matter which directory the site is in" question is: YES. Htaccess does not appear to be relative to the current path.